# styrene confusion

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am studying NMR and while looking at styrene, I can't figure out why the two hydrogens on the terminal double bond are not equivalent. Is it because one is closer to the ring in position than the other and there is not free axis motion? If so, why are the hydrogens in the ring directly left and right of the branch still equivalent?

Comment: Did you realize that one terminal hydrogen on the double bond is *cis* and the other  terminal hydrogen is *trans*  to the third hydrogen on the double bond? That means those two terminal hydrogens are not chemically and magnetically equivalent.